# EF will not return user if user is not current user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a weird problem with Entity Framework, where if I attempt to access a user variable that's not the current user it throws an error. I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 with SignalR (this is in a SignalR hub) and SimpleMembership to provide authentication.

Here's the code I have:

```
using (CfDb db = new CfDb())
{
    var currUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == UserID);
    if (currUser != null && currUser.Challenge == Challenge)
    {
        var posts = db.Posts.Where(a => a.Privacy == "public").OrderByDescending(a => a.PostedTime);
        List<int> People = new List<int>();
        foreach (Post post in posts)
        {
            People.Add(post.Poster.ID);
        }
    }
}
```

If `post.Poster` is the same as the current logged in user it will return the correct user who posted the post, but if not, `post.Poster` will be null and `post.Poster.ID` will throw an exception. If I take out all the currUser code, (and just do if(true)), the error still occurs so it doesn't seem to relate to the currUser variable. I'm not even doing anything with WebSecurity - removing `using System.Web.Security;` from the top of the page doesn't fix it. I have no idea how it seems to know who the current user is, and it's seeming pretty weird that it's only returning posters if it's the current user.

Here's the important parts of my code first model:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Realname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Friends { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Challenge { get; set; }
    public School School { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double Vici { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Classroom> Classes { get; set; }
}
public class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double Vici { get; set; }
    public User Poster { get; set; }
    public Classroom Class { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Likes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Privacy { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime PostedTime { get; set; }
}
public class CfDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasMany(e => e.Likes).WithMany();
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(e => e.Friends).WithMany();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasMany(e => e.Comments).WithMany();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasMany(e => e.Likes).WithMany();
    }
}
```

In my database, the Poster_ID columns are all correctly set, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to tell EF to eager load your User property, access it in the query, or make it virtual so that the proxy can lazy load them - similar to how you have your collections set up.  It works with the current user because the object has already been loaded.

eg:

```
var posts = db.Posts.Where(a => a.Privacy == "public")
                    .OrderByDescending(a => a.PostedTime)
                    .Select(a=> new { Post = a, User = a.Poster });

foreach (var post in posts) { 
    People.Add(post.User.Id);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that will make it lazy loaded.  If you are processing 100 posts, it's going to execute a new query against the db for each user as you try to access post.User.Id.  If you leave it as virtual and use a query like the one I posted, you will eagerly load the related User.  This common hiccup in ORMs is called the N+1 problem.